# Integrate 2D kernel density estimate

Tags: python, integration, kernel-density, probability-density

I have a `x,y` distribution of points for which I obtain the `KDE` through [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). This is my code and how the output looks (the `x,y` data can be obtained from [here](http://pastebin.com/RXbHzGfV)):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Obtain data from file.
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', unpack=True)
m1, m2 = data[0], data[1]
xmin, xmax = min(m1), max(m1)
ymin, ymax = min(m2), max(m2)

# Perform a kernel density estimate (KDE) on the data
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, x.shape)

# Define the number that will determine the integration limits
x1, y1 = 2.5, 1.5

# Perform integration?

# Plot the results:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set limits
plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin,ymax)
# KDE density plot
plt.imshow(np.rot90(f), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
# Draw contour lines
cset = plt.contour(x,y,f)
plt.clabel(cset, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.colorbar()
# Plot point
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='r', s=35)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

The red point with coordinates `(x1, y1)` has (like every point in the 2D plot) an associated value given by `f` (the kernel or `KDE`) between 0 and 0.42. Let's say that `f(x1, y1) = 0.08`.

I need to integrate `f` with integration limits in `x` and `y` given by those regions where `f` evaluates to *less* than `f(x1, y1)`, ie: `f(x, y)<0.08`.

For what I've seen `python` can perform integration of *functions* and one dimensional arrays through numerical integration, but I haven't seen anything that would let me perform a numerical integration on a 2D array (the `f` kernel) Furthermore, I'm not sure how I would even recognize the regions given by that particular condition (ie: `f(x, y)`less than a given value)

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using monte carlo integration.  It is a little slow, and there is randomness in the solution.  The error is inversely proportional to the square root of the sample size, while the running time is directly proportional to the sample size (where sample size refers to the monte carlo sample (10000 in my example below), not the size of your data set).  Here is some simple code using your `kernel` object.

```
#Compute the point below which to integrate
iso = kernel((x1,y1))

#Sample from your KDE distribution
sample = kernel.resample(size=10000)

#Filter the sample
insample = kernel(sample) < iso

#The integral you want is equivalent to the probability of drawing a point 
#that gets through the filter
integral = insample.sum() / float(insample.shape[0])
print integral
```

I get approximately 0.2 as the answer for your data set.

Comment: Amazingly simple, I clearly need to read some more statistics. Thank you very much!

Comment: Beware, this Monte Carlo implementation is probably incorrect. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35903712/1391441

Comment: @Gabriel I think this solution is actually correct for this question.  I looked at the other question you linked to.  Here are my thoughts.  There are two different bounds of integration getting mixed up here.  In this question, you pretty clearly state that you want to integrate over the set of x, y where f(x,y) < f(x1,y1) (right?).  This solution does that.  In your other question, it isn't clear to me whether you're looking to integrate over the same set as in this question or over the set of x, y where x < x1 and y < y1.  If the latter, dfb's answer is correct.

Comment: You are absolutely correct jcrudy, I didn't notice that the integration limits where different. Both your answer and the one in that other question are correct. What is actually incorrect is the answer by cqcn1991 (below). Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it is available

`kernel.integrate_box([-np.inf,-np.inf], [2.5,1.5])`

Answer (score 1):

A direct way is to `integrate`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[5, 0], [0, 10]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.show()

sample = np.array(zip(x, y))
kde = sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity().fit(sample)
def f_kde(x,y):
    return np.exp((kde.score_samples([[x,y]])))

point = x1, y1
integrate.nquad(f_kde, [[-np.inf, x1],[-np.inf, y1]])
```

The problem is that, this is very slow if you do it in a large scale. For example, if you want to plot the `x,y` line at x (0,100), it would take a long time to calculate.

Notice: I used `kde` from `sklearn`, but I believe you can also change it into other form as well.

---

Using the `kernel` as defined in the original question:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy import integrate

def integ_func(kde, x1, y1):

    def f_kde(x, y):
        return kde((x, y))

    integ = integrate.nquad(f_kde, [[-np.inf, x1], [-np.inf, y1]])

    return integ

# Obtain data from file.
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', unpack=True)
# Perform a kernel density estimate (KDE) on the data
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data)

# Define the number that will determine the integration limits
x1, y1 = 2.5, 1.5
print integ_func(kernel, x1, y1)
```

Comment: cqcn1991 I can't get this example to work. Could you expand your code to make it able to run?

Comment: @Gabriel I change it with a full example, but leave out some `import`. `import` in python is just a disaster for me.

Comment: `KernelDensity` is not imported correctly, you should use: `from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity`. How are you defining `inf`? I get a `NameError: name 'inf' is not defined` with your code. Also, where is the point that should be used as the integration limit `(x1,y1)`?

Comment: Just updated the `inf` import before your comment, and I add `x1`, `y1` as well

Comment: Yes, you could simply use the `kernel` as defined in my question instead of using `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity()`.

Comment: @Gabriel  Additioanlly, I don't think you should use it as `nquad` instead of `integrate.nquad`. It makes the code less expressive. `nquad` is used to tell it's an `n-d` integrate instead of a `1d` integrate.

Comment: cqcn1991 please see the comments section of jcrudy's answer (above) I didn't notice that your answer uses different integration limits. The original question asks to integrate in the domain `f(x,y)<(f(x1,y1)` *not* `(-inf,x1) & (-inf,x1)`.

Comment: @Gabriel my mistake, I totally misunderstood the question. The answer I gave here is irrelavant to your question at all. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's ok, it introduced me to `nquad` which I wasn't familiar with. It also sparked [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35902531/1391441) which turned into an interesting discussion.