# Thread error: can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, montecarlo, kernel-density

Here's a `MWE` of a much larger code I'm using. It performs a Monte Carlo integration over a KDE ([kernel density estimate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)) for all values located below a certain threshold (the integration method was suggested over at this question: [Integrate 2D kernel density estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822282/integrate-2d-kernel-density-estimate?rq=1)) iteratively for a number of points in a list and returns a list made of these results.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading

# Define KDE integration function.
def kde_integration(m_list):

    # Put some of the values from the m_list into two new lists.
    m1, m2 = [], []
    for item in m_list:
        # x data.
        m1.append(item[0])
        # y data.
        m2.append(item[1])

    # Define limits.
    xmin, xmax = min(m1), max(m1)
    ymin, ymax = min(m2), max(m2)

    # Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:
    x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
    values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)

    # This list will be returned at the end of this function.
    out_list = []

    # Iterate through all points in the list and calculate for each the integral
    # of the KDE for the domain of points located below the value of that point
    # in the KDE.
    for point in m_list:

        # Compute the point below which to integrate.
        iso = kernel((point[0], point[1]))

        # Sample KDE distribution
        sample = kernel.resample(size=1000)

        #Choose number of cores and split input array.
        cores = 4
        torun = np.array_split(sample, cores, axis=1)

        # Print number of active threads.
        print threading.active_count()

        #Calculate
        pool = Pool(processes=cores)
        results = pool.map(kernel, torun)

        #Reintegrate and calculate results
        insample_mp = np.concatenate(results) < iso

        # Integrate for all values below iso.
        integral = insample_mp.sum() / float(insample_mp.shape[0])

        # Append integral value for this point to list that will return.
        out_list.append(integral)

    return out_list


# Generate some random two-dimensional data:
def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

# Create list to pass to KDE integral function.
m_list = []
for i in range(100):
    m1, m2 = measure(5)
    m_list.append(m1.tolist())
    m_list.append(m2.tolist())

# Call KDE integration function.
print 'Integral result: ', kde_integration(m_list)
```

The `multiprocessing` in the code was suggested over at this question [Speed up sampling of kernel estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538790/speed-up-sampling-of-kernel-estimate) to speed up the code (which it does up to ~3.4x).

The code works ok until I try to pass to the KDE function a list of more than ~62-63 elements (ie: I set a value over 63 in the line `for i in range(100)`) If I do that I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/gauss_kde_temp.py", line 78, in <module>
    print 'Integral result: ', kde_integration(m_list)
  File "~/gauss_kde_temp.py", line 48, in kde_integration
    pool = Pool(processes=cores)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._worker_handler.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 494, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

usually (9 out of 10 times) around the active thread `374`. I'm *way* out of my league in terms of `python` coding here and I have no clue as to how I could fix this issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

### Add

I tried adding a `while` loop to prevent the code from using too many threads. What I did was replacing the `print threading.active_count()` line by this bit of code:

```
    # Print number of active threads.
    exit_loop = True
    while exit_loop:
        if threading.active_count() < 300:
            exit_loop = False
        else:
            # Pause for 10 seconds.
            time.sleep(10.)
            print 'waiting: ', threading.active_count()
```

The code halted (ie: got stuck inside the loop) when it reached `302` active threads. I waited for more than 10 minutes and the code never exited the loop and the number of active threads never dropped from `302`. Shouldn't the number of active threads diminish after a while?