# how to integrate a 2d kernel density estimate without sampling

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to integrate a 2d kernel density estimator, [basically like this guy here is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822282/integrate-2d-kernel-density-estimate), by in a more "scipythonic" way (sampling ten thousand times and then summing up just does not cut it for me, python is expensive with for loops, how to use scipy in this case?)

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the density estimate on a regular grid and integrating?

Comment: `kernel.integrate_box`?