# Different integration results using Monte Carlo vs scipy.integrate.nquad

Tags: python, scipy, montecarlo, integral

The MWE below shows two ways of integrating the same 2D kernel density estimate, obtained for [this data](http://pastebin.com/NtQH0yXb) using the `stats.gaussian_kde()` function.

The integration is performed for all `(x, y)` below the threshold point `(x1, y1)`, which defines the upper integration limits (lower integration limits are `-infinity`; see MWE).

- The `int1` function uses simple a Monte Carlo approach.
- The `int2` function uses the [scipy.integrate.nquad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) function.

The issue is that `int1` (ie: the Monte Carlo method) gives systematically larger values for the integral than `int2`. I don't know why this happens.

Here's an example of the integral values obtained after 200 runs of `int1` (blue histogram) versus the integral result given by `int2` (red vertical line):

[image]

What is the origin of this difference in the resulting integral value?

---

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy import integrate


def int1(kernel, x1, y1):
    # Compute the point below which to integrate
    iso = kernel((x1, y1))

    # Sample KDE distribution
    sample = kernel.resample(size=50000)

    # Filter the sample
    insample = kernel(sample) < iso

    # The integral is equivalent to the probability of drawing a
    # point that gets through the filter
    integral = insample.sum() / float(insample.shape[0])

    return integral


def int2(kernel, x1, y1):

    def f_kde(x, y):
        return kernel((x, y))

    # 2D integration in: (-inf, x1), (-inf, y1).
    integral = integrate.nquad(f_kde, [[-np.inf, x1], [-np.inf, y1]])

    return integral


# Obtain data from file.
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', unpack=True)
# Perform a kernel density estimate (KDE) on the data
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data)

# Define the threshold point that determines the integration limits.
x1, y1 = 2.5, 1.5

i2 = int2(kernel, x1, y1)
print i2

int1_vals = []
for _ in range(200):
    i = int1(kernel, x1, y1)
    int1_vals.append(i)
    print i
```

---

**Add**

Notice that this question originated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571039/1391441). At first I didn't notice that the answer was mistaken in the integration limits used, which explains why the results between `int1` and `int2` are different.

`int1` is integrating in the domain `f(x,y)<f(x1,y1)` (where f is the kernel density estimate), while `int2` integrates in the domain `(x,y)<(x1,y1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You resample the distribution

```
sample = kernel.resample(size=50000)
```

and then compute the probability for each sampled point is less than the probability at the bound

```
insample = kernel(sample) < iso
```

This is incorrect. Consider the bounds (0,100) and assume your data has u=(0,0) and cov=[[100,0],[0,100]].  Points (0,50) and (50,0) have the same probability in this kernel, but only one of them is in the bounds.  Since both pass the test, you are over sampling.

You should be testing whether each point in `sample` is inside the bounds, then compute the probability. Something like

```
def int1(kernel, x1, y1):
    # Sample KDE distribution                                                                                                              
    sample = kernel.resample(size=100)

    include = (sample < np.repeat([[x1],[y1]],sample.shape[1],axis=1)).all(axis=0)
    integral = include.sum() / float(sample.shape[1])
    return integral
```

I tested this using the following code

```
def measure(n):

    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    return m1,m2

a = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde( np.vstack(measure(1000)) )
print(int1(a,-10,-10))
print(int2(a,-10,-10))
print(int1(a,0,0))
print(int2(a,-0,-0))
```

Yields

```
0.0
(4.304674927251112e-232, 4.6980863813551415e-230)
0.26
(0.25897626178338407, 1.4536217446381293e-08)
```

Monte Carlo integration should work like this

- Sample N random values (uniformly, not from your distribution) over some subset of the possible values of x/y (below I bound it by 10 SDs from mean).
- For each random value compute kernel(rand_x,rand_y)
- Compute the sum and multiply by (volume)/N_samples

In code:

```
def mc_wo_sample(kernel,x1,y1,lboundx,lboundy):
    nsamples = 50000
    volume = (x1-lboundx)*(y1-lboundy)
    # generate uniform points in range                                                                                                     
    xrand = np.random.rand(nsamples,1)*(x1-lboundx) + lboundx
    yrand = np.random.rand(nsamples,1)*(y1-lboundy) + lboundy
    randvals = np.hstack((xrand,yrand)).transpose()
    print randvals.shape
    return (volume*kernel(randvals).sum())/nsamples
```

Running the following

```
   print(int1(a,-9,-9))
   print(int2(a,-9,-9))
   print(mc_wo_sample(a,-9,-9,-10,-10))
   print(int1(a,0,0))
   print(int2(a,-0,-0))
   print(mc_wo_sample(a,0,0,-10,-10))
```

yields

```
0.0
(4.012958496109042e-70, 6.7211236076277e-71)
4.08538890986e-70
0.36
(0.37101621760650216, 1.4670898180664756e-08)
0.361614657674
```

Comment: I thought so. The above code fails with: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,50000) (2,2) `. Have you tested it? Can you make it run?

Comment: Change `sample.shape[0] ` to `sample.shape[1]`. That value should be the number of samples.  I'm translating to your example using my own test code.

Comment: Thanks dfb. It compiles now but the results of the MC method with your code are ~`0.06`. This is very different to the `nquad` result of  ~`0.194`. The MC method in my question gives much closer values for the integral.

Comment: See my edit - we don't want to sum the probabilities, we just test whether we hit inside the box or not on the samples.

Comment: Not only does this answer solve the issue in my question, it is also many times faster. Thank you very much! You should remove the `iso = kernel((x1, y1))` line in your `int1` function, it is not used. Thanks again!

Comment: @Gabriel  - After a brief look, I'm not sure the previous question works correctly.  Monte Carlo intregration requires you to sample random points uniformly - in my int1 function, this is handled by `kernel.sample`.  I've written a function above that does MC w/o that function, hope that helps some.

Comment: How do you obtain `lboundx,lboundy`? Something like this perhaps: `lboundx = np.mean(data[0])+10*np.std(data[0])`? In the tests I just made your `int1` function returns values very close to `nquad`, while your new function does not.

Comment: That's not quite right because you have to use the covariance, but it's probably a decent approximation. It does work with my example above, but I'll try with your data later

Comment: One other quick thought - Try increasing the `n_samples` *10 or so.

Comment: I'm not using the data file anymore, I use the random values generated with the `measure()` function to test all integration methods. As I said, `int1` works perfectly (ie: the results match the `nquad` value) but your new function is off by *a lot*. I increased the sample by 10, no changes.

Comment: Hmm.. I've pasted the parameters I'm using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105949/discussion-between-dfb-and-gabriel).