# scipy intergrate evaluate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to integrate a two-dimension KDE function with SciPy following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571039), but I'm getting an error that I provide more arguments than are required.

```py
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sts

# data 
rvs = np.append(stats.norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=3,size=(2000,1)),
                stats.norm.rvs(loc=1,scale=2,size=(2000,1)),
                axis=1)

# fit kde
kde = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(rvs.T)

# failed attempts to calculate the integral:
print(integrate.nquad(kde, [[-1, 1],[-1, 1]])) # --> error: evaluate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
print(integrate.dblquad(kde, -1, 1, -1, 1)) # --> error: evaluate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

According to the documentation for [Scipy.nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html), I must provide a `func` object as the first argument. Is the KDE missing a required type? Can I extract the function that works for integration from the KDE object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the integrate function, it is with how the `kde` function accepts arguments - it only takes one argument (and a class instance argument, which is why it says 2 arguments). So you need to pack your input arguments to `kde` in a list or a tuple.

To align with how the integrate function passes arguments, you could just make a lambda from kde and apply the integrate function on that, like so

```py
kde2 = lambda a, b: kde([a,b])
print(integrate.nquad(kde2, [[-1, 1],[-1, 1]]))
print(integrate.dblquad(kde2, -1, 1, -1, 1))
```

Comment: This calculation returns 2-dim result ```(0.08394255210560318, 9.319495409343757e-16)```.  Why?

Comment: I believe the second result value is the error on the integration. in the documentation it states: `The maximum of the estimates of the absolute error in the various integration results.`